# How to wrap items horizontally in React Native flexbox?

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, native

I'm trying to get my items to wrap so there are multiple items per line. But it's just refusing to do it.

If there is enough room the next item should be on the same line.

e.g am i grey?, delete me - should be on the same line because there is more than enough space etc.

Hi, that will make the items go off the screen to the right, and then scrolling will occur. It should fit as many items on the line as it can till it reaches the right-hand side of the screen, and then drop to the next line etc..

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I am so sorry for the miss information. I was wrong, what you want is achievable by doing the styles in this prop `contentContainerStyle`. FlatList uses ScrollView props which has that prop that styles the FlatList content

See [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle) for more information about the prop.

By adding `flexDirection: 'row'` to `contentContainerStyle` it makes the content horizontal and adding `flexWrap: 'wrap'` completes the desired design by changing lines when it doesn't have space

See this [example](https://snack.expo.io/@mpn7/ZmxhdC)

Answer (score 2):

You should put `flexDirection:row` in the `TouchableOpacity`, you don't want the `FlatList`to be in a row you want whats in inside to be

**EDIT**

On `FlatList` you have a prop called `horizontal` set that to true. It will probably have the desired design

```
<FlatList horizontal={true} />
```

Comment: Hi, that will make the items go off the screen to the right, and then scrolling will occur. It should fit as many items on the line as it can till it reaches the right hand side of the screen, and then drop to the next line etc..

Comment: I don't think you can achieve what you want with `FlatList`, the most alike design would be to set `numColumns` to the number of collumns you want and delete the `horizontal` prop, since FlatList doesnt support `wrap`